# Excel, Visual Basic Changing the Range a formula uses

Tags: excel, range, vba

The below code I found online and I started adapting it.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A As Range, B As Range, Inte As Range, r As Range
    Set A = Range("A:A")
    Set Inte = Intersect(A, Target)
    If Inte Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each r In Inte
            r.Offset(-1, 1).Value = Now
        Next r
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

What I really need to change is instead of this code applying to the entire A column, I need it to start at a specific cell, and apply to every nth cell after that, in a given column.

Can I accomplish that by just modifying the syntax below, or do I need to write a new formula?

Comment: what cell should it start from?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your wishes

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A As Range, B As Range, Inte As Range, r As Range
    Set A = Range("B5:C15") ' "B5:C15" - range in which we want to track changes (сan change)
    Set Inte = Intersect(A, Target)
    If Inte Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each r In Inte
            ActiveSheet.Range("E" & r.Row).Value = Now  ' "Е" - сolumn for insert the date of change (сan change)
        Next r
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for responding. That indeed helps clarify some of the ways to define range. Here is a better picture of what I am trying to do:

Solution 1: 
I have kind of solved it in a very inefficient way. I have a repeating table on a spread sheet that we just C&P as needed. As long as everyone C&P with the same spacing, my solution works by changing the range to this:

Set A = Range("A5,A10,A15,A20,A25")  And then I just add as many increments as I think we will need.

Obviously this is not a desirable way of doing this; I would like to know how to code it so it will do every 5th row in the entire A column, to infinity.

Solution 2:
Probably more advanced than I care to get to in visual basic, but ideally I would like the script to search for a specific word in a cell, and then execute on the next row down. So if it finds the word "Current" in Cell A4, it will execute the script on Cell A5.

If I could make this work, then it would not matter if someone messed up the spacing.

I appreciate your help!